# Search content over a web application using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a web app for weather forecast. it was written in python using flask, and hosted over ec2.
I want to create a python function that will open the browser, input a value to my search bar, click on the submit button and get back the answer.
The final idea is to implement it as an aws lambda function so i can run it everyday at XX:XX o'clock.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're describing a Weather API. I would suggest to use an API instead of using a browser (even headless) to create your request.

Here an example of public Weather API: [here](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3)

**EDIT:** [CloudWatch Scheduled Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html)

To trigger your Lambda function at specific time during the day, you can use Amazon CloudWatch Events. You create a scheduled `Rule` at 6pm everyday with your Lambda function as a `Target`.

Comment: hi @Mickael, i've used this exact website and APIs in my website. (in short: my project was was about python, flask, nginx etc..) so i've used this website in order to create my project. afterwards i've made some more modifications and now i want to create a lambda function that will search for a specific city, everyday at 18:00 and store the results in my dynamodb table. (i know how to store info in my db, what i don't know is how to initiate this search using lambda at a specific time)

Comment: I've edited my answer to propose a solution with Amazon CloudWatch to schedule call of your Lambda function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Mickael. i'm interested in the Lambda function at this point - is it possible for you to direct me to the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html